# C++ Palindrome Bool Function (Using Pointer)

Tags: c++, function, boolean, palindrome

How to create a Palindrome function in C++? I'm using 2 functions types(bool and void). 
Here is my code so far (I would really appreciate any help with this, and why my code is not working?) Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void reverse(char *);  
bool isPalindrome(char *);  

int main()  
{  
    char a[10];  
    cout << "string ";  
    cin.getline(a, 10);  
    if (palindrome(a))  
        cout << "true";   
    else  
        cout << "false";  
    return 0;  
}  
void reverse(char *s)  
{  
    char *point = s;  
    int i, min;  
    for (i = 0; *point != '\0'; i++)  
        point++;  
        min = i;  
        point--;  
    for (i = min; i > 0; i--)  
   {  
        cout << *point--;  
   }  
}  
bool ispalindrome(char *s)  
{  
    bool status;  
    char *original = s;  
    char *point = s;  
    reverse(point);        
    for (int i = 0; point != '\0'; i++)  
    {  
        if (point[i] == original[i])  
        status = true;  
        else  
        status = false;  
    }  
    return status;  
}
```

Comment: So, before I read all this code... are you getting an error message or is the answer just not right?  Add that detail and then expound on it.  If it's an error message please give it.  If it's just not right, show some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It gives me this error: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1. address=0x7fffSfc87000)

Comment: when you set status = false you should break the loop (and should be a while, not a for one) because if the middle 2 letters are equals it returns true, even if the other letters are all differents

Comment: General comments: 1. This is not c++, 2. Your `reverse()` function does not make sense, 3. Your loop in the `isPalindrome()` function is incorrect. You could simplify this by simply iterating from both ends of the string checking both characters for equality. Or use some standard library algorithms (`std::reverse()`, and `std::equal()`)

Comment: @hidrargyro thanks for the explanation. I did some tests and I now understand how to use status = false.

Comment: @Nim I know my work needs lots of corrections :) I got it work now and learned few key things. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to reverse the string to check if its palindrome.

the algorithm works like:

get the length of the string;
loop from zero to length of string by 2;
compare the characters on position loop count with lenght minus loop count minus 1;
if the are not equal its not a palindrom;
its a palindrome if the loop finished;

for example: "test":
first step: compare 't' with 't'
second step: compare 'e' with 's' --> not a palindrom

for example "palap":
first step: compare 'p' with 'p'
second step: compare 'a' with 'a'
third step: compare 'l' with 'l'
now we know that it is a palindrom.

try thisone:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int palindrom(char * s){
  int i;
  int l = strlen(s);
  for(i=0;i<=l/2;i++)
    if(s[i]!=s[l-i-1]) return 0;
  return 1;
}

int main(void) {
  char * test = "test";
  char * pal = "palap";
  printf("%s %d", test, palindrom(test));
  printf("%s %d", pal, palindrom(pal));
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It's bad form to give code, why not describe the solution? The OP is clearly a beginner...

Comment: ok, sorry, i will explain it, just give me a few minutes, my english is not perfect :)

Comment: @linluk your code is great. On this part: if(s[i]!=[l-i-1]) are you using -1 in reference to ('\0' or null terminator)?

Comment: because the first element of a string has index 0 and not index 1. so the string "test" has length 4, but the last character ('t') has index 3.

Answer (score 2):

Several things that can be improved here.  Your most immediate problem is that the for loop in your `isPalindrome` function doesn't terminate.  Change the terminating condition to `point[i] != '\0'`.

Secondly the reverse function is not actually reversing.  if you want to use this algorithm you'll need to allocate memory for the reversed string.  A better way though is to put a pointer at the front of the string, a pointer at the end of the string, and then walk them to the middle of the string.

Comment: For the second part, how do I put pointers at the front and end of the string?

Comment: The first three lines of your reverse function are doing this already.  After the first loop of that function finishes, then `point` points to the end of the string.  Back it up one step (like you do) so it's pointing at the last character (or terminate the loop one iteration early).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answer from @linluk using pointers instead of indices...

```
#include <cstring>
bool palindrome(char *s)  
{
    for (char *e = strchr(s, '\0'); -- e > s; ++ s)
        if (*e != *s)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Initially, `e`, points to the end of the string and `s` points to the beginning. In each iteration, `e` steps backward while `s` steps forward until they meet in the middle. If, they ever point to a different character from one another, the test fails.